# How to pass value to another function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to get Google Maps `address_components` and have only managed to get do the following:

```
  $(function() {
    $("#spot_address").autocomplete({
      //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
      source: function(request, response) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
          for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++)
          {
              var addr = results[0].address_components[i];
              if (addr.types[0] == 'country') 
                  country: addr.long_name;
          }
          response($.map(results, function(item) {
            return {
              label:  item.formatted_address,
              value: item.formatted_address,
              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
            }
          }));
        })
      },

  //This bit is executed upon selection of an address

  select: function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.country);
    $("#spot_lat").val(ui.item.latitude);
    $("#spot_lng").val(ui.item.longitude);
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
    marker.setPosition(location);
    map.setCenter(location);
  }
});
```

});

Over here I am trying to test the `alert(ui.country)` when the item is selected from the autocomplete list. However, I am only getting `undefined` instead. It's not passed. What have I done wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: If `ui` wasn't passed then `alert(ui.country)` would result in an error instead of alerting undefined. Try `console.log(ui)` instead and see what it gives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it done with a help of a friend.

Here's the full code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#address").autocomplete({
      //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
      source: function(request, response) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++)
              {
                  var addr = results[0].address_components[i],
                      country1;
                  if (addr.types[0] == 'country') 
                      country1= addr.long_name;
              }
          response($.map(results, function(item) {
            return {
              label:  item.formatted_address,
              value: item.formatted_address,
              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng(),
              country: country1
            }
          }));
        })
      },
      //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
      select: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.country);
        $("#latitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
        $("#longitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
        marker.setPosition(location);
        map.setCenter(location);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if property ui.country exists FireBug or Chrome Inspect Scripts

And If property country exist in **item** then just:

```
response($.map(results, function(item) {
            return {
              label:  item.formatted_address,
              value: item.formatted_address,
              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng(),
              country: item.country, // Or other location of this property
            }
          }));
```

Comment: @victor But what doesn't work ? Where exactly Try country: "Test", and then alert(ui.country); in fce

Comment: I can't select the items from the autocomplete when I pass `country: "Test"`.

Answer (score 0):

Add to

```
      response($.map(results, function(item) {
        return {
          country: item.country
```

Comment: Try adding to `return { item: item,` then `alert(ui.item)` to see all the properties.

Comment: I actually tried JinDave approach, but still got `undefined`.

Comment: So you've tried to add to the original return `country: item.country,` and then in your response method `alert(ui.country)`?  Are you sure your response is a valid address (ie not an error, which would not return a country)?

Comment: Yeah, I am certain that the result is valid.